# How to use contains in SQL to search for keywords from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, contains

I am using MS SQL server 2012, and I have two tables:

1) `Keyword_table` that contains list of keywords, like:

```
keyword, nvarchar(50)
-------------------
web
book
AI
work
...
```

2) `art_table` that contains IDs and list of articles, like:

```
artID,  int         art,  nvarchar(MAX)
---------------------------------------
1                  The Web is a system of ...
2                  AI is the intelligence exhibited by machines or software ...
3                  The Web includes Web 1.0, Web 2.0 and Web 3.0
4                  The work done by ...
....
```

I want to search each keyword in the keyword_table to get the number of articles that contain that keyword, for example, based on the data above the result should be like this:

```
keyword            No of articles
----------------------------------
web                2
book               0
AI                 1
work               1
```

The art_table has few millions records, and it has full text index on art column, and I know that I can use `contains` to search for a simple term (single word/phrase) like this:

```
select *
from art_table
where contains (art, 'web')
```

And to count the number of the articles that contains `web`:

```
select count(*)
from art_table
where contains (art, 'web')
```

BUT how to do it for searching the ALL keywords in keyword_table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @AdamCaviness I am using SQL Server's Full-Text Search but I am asking how to use "contains predicate" for searching keywords from another table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone come across with the same need, here is a suggested answer:

```
DECLARE @kword nvarchar(200);
DECLARE keywordCursor CURSOR FOR(SELECT keyword FROM keyword_table);
OPEN keywordCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM keywordCursor INTO @kword;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO keyword_occ(keyword,occ)
    VALUES(@kword,(SELECT count(*) FROM art_table WHERE CONTAINS(art, @kword)));
    FETCH NEXT FROM keywordCursor INTO @kword;
END;
CLOSE keywordCursor;
DEALLOCATE keywordCursor;
GO
```

Where `keyword_occ` is a table (`keyword` nvarchar(200), `occ` int) to save the required result.

I wish if I could avoid `WHILE loop`, however, this script works well and fast with millions indexed records!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select a.* from art_table a
inner join keyword_table b
on a.art like '%' + b.keyword + '%'
```

That should give you a match based on the keyword and return all records that has the keyword somewhere in it.

[Edit]

Perhaps try this?

```
select a.* from art_table a
inner join keyword_table b
on contains(a.art,  b.keyword)
```

Note I haven't syntax tested this :)

Comment: thanks for your reply. It works, however, the performance is very bad. The art_table has few millions records so I created a full text index on art column, and that's why I need to use 'Contains' and not 'Like'

Comment: "select a.* from art_table a inner join keyword_table b on contains(a.art,  b.keyword)" is Incorrect Syntax :)

Comment: It was worth a shot :)  Just a question, it seems to be a lot of records that you're trying to join on for a keyword search.  Is there any intention to reduce the number of search terms?  If you have millions of rows then you may as well join on the English Language :)

Comment: The art_table contains millions of English articles and I'm trying to do some analysis with few hundred keywords :)

Comment: I can't think of any way beyond my original suggested query to achieve the result you're after and get improved performance beyond ensuring your indexes are ok.  Sorry :(